# In flutter I need to hide button after 1 mins

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub, dart-null-safety

I need to hide button after 1 mins but while reloading and again restarting application it will not show again once it hide it will not repeated

Comment: can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

Use `shared_preferences` (or any persist memory) to persist the state of the button over restarts.

See [Store key-value data on disk](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/key-value) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use db to handle restarting application case.

You can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to store a flag about visibility.

```dart
class _GState extends State<G> {
  static const String _buttonVisibilityKey = "DoneWIthButtonX";

  bool showButton = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _buttonActionChecker().then((value) async {
      // return false if button never showed up, activate the timer to hide
      print(value);
      if (!value) {
        showButton = true;
        setState(() {});
        Future.delayed(Duration(minutes: 1)).then((value) async {
          showButton = false;
          SharedPreferences.getInstance()
              .then((value) => value.setBool(_buttonVisibilityKey, true));
          setState(() {});
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  /// is the button have been shown already return true
  Future<bool> _buttonActionChecker() async {
    return SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((value) {
      return value.getBool(_buttonVisibilityKey) ?? false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: showButton
            ? FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                },
              )
            : null,
);
  }
}
```